# Transition Div Not Working

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a simple example of trying to move a div by setting its left property. When I refresh the page, the div shows up immediately with left of 650. No transition is happening. I've tried various changes to my code, but it's always the same result. Below is the current state. What am I missing?

HTML:

```
<div ng-style="pos" class="box"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
    position:absolute;
    top:250px;
    left:100px;
    background-color:tan;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    transition: top 1800ms linear, left 1800ms linear;
}
```

JS:

```
function moveController($scope) {
    $scope.pos = {
        top: 250,
        left: 100
    }
    $scope.pos.left = 650;
}
```

As you can see, I want the box to move over a time of 1800ms. The box shows up on the screen with the correct formatting based on the CSS, so that part is working. However, no transition. Why?

Comment: What is calling the moveController function? Maybe you need to set a timeout or a delay on the animation?

Comment: It would seem it won't work until the page is loaded https://jsfiddle.net/dgx4ps35/ It only works when the JavaScript is set to run after onLoad. onDomready and in the head or body tags gives the same results you describe.

Comment: @spaceman That was it. If I set `$scope.pos.left` when responding to a click event after everything is loaded, it worked. If you'd like to post the answer, I'll accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add a timeout or delay before you changing the styles:

```
function moveController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.pos = {
        top: 250,
        left: 100
    }

    $timeout(function(){
         $scope.pos.left = 650;
    }, 1000)

}
```

since the DOM rendered **after** the controller initialized, so the initial position for DIV would be `top: 250, left: 650` if no delay added.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are assigning both values at the same time.

> ```
> $timeout(function () {
>    $scope.pos.left = 650;
> }, 10);
> ```

this way you'll be able to set an initial value and change it later!

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `angular.element(document).ready()` in your controller in order to run the action when the dom is ready.

So in your controller you can use:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function(){
    //action onload here
});
```